# Linq: Adding Extra 'Where' Clause Gives Random Results

Tags: c#, .net, linq, flickr

I'm a beginner in using Linq and a lot of it is completely confusing right now.

I downloaded and used the LinqFlickr library from http://linqflickr.codeplex.com. I think however that this is just my lack of understanding about Linq. There isn't much documentation on the LinqFlickr project for me to go on.

If I run the following code, if the username string is blank, it runs fine and returns photos with a specific tag. But if there is a username in it, it should refine the previous results by specific users, instead it gives me a bunch of random photos.

```
            var photos = (from ph in context.Photos
                      where
                      ph.SearchMode == SearchMode.TagsOnly
                      && ph.SearchText == tag
                      && ph.PhotoSize == PhotoSize.Small
                      && ph.Extras == (ExtrasOption.Owner_Name |  ExtrasOption.Date_Taken)
                      select ph);

            if (username != "")
            {
                string personId = (from people in context.Peoples
                                where 
                                people.Username == username
                                select people.Id).First();
                photos = photos.Where(q => q.NsId == personId) ;
            }

            photos = photos.Take(10);
```

I tried using some debugging tools such as LinqPad and MetaLinq but I haven't been able to solve it with them.

Also, I'm sure my Linq query could be made in one query which would be great, but please explain it so a Linq newbie can understand!

Comment: As a side note, `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username)` is better than `username!=""`

Comment: As a side note, !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) is even better.

Comment: @ipavlic, @A.R.: Better how? Surely that depends on exactly *what* the OP actually wants to test for. (Admittedly I'm nitpicking here. In most cases either `IsNullOrEmpty` or `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` would be the better option.)

Comment: Yes that does sound better - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks fine. My guess would be that this is a bug (or unintuitive by-design behaviour) in Athena where an extra "chained" `where` clause causes the original `where` clause to be forgotten.

Assemble the second query independently (i.e. all the constraints in one big `where` clause) and check that this fixes things. If it does, it's definitely a bug in the API. You can work around this by using [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to assemble and expand the predicate for the `where` clause dynamically. Here's how this might look:

```
// Original predicate without userId constraint
Expression<Func<Photo, bool>> predicate = ph =>  
        ph.SearchMode == SearchMode.TagsOnly
     && ph.SearchText == tag
     && ph.PhotoSize == PhotoSize.Small
     && ph.Extras == (ExtrasOption.Owner_Name |  ExtrasOption.Date_Taken);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) 
{
    // Build the userId constraint into the predicate.

    var personId = (from people in context.Peoples
                    where  people.Username == username
                    select people.Id).First();

    // "And" combines the predicates
    // "Expand" removes the use of invocation expressions, which 
    // some LINQ providers have problems with.
    predicate = predicate.And(q => q.NsId == personId).Expand();
}

// Final result
var photos = context.Photos.Where(predicate).Take(10);
```

Comment: Looks great, and I can understand it too :)

But I'm getting and error saying "And() - No argument takes 1 parameters"

Comment: @user106565: Did you include a reference to `LinqKit.dll` and add a `using LinqKit;` directive to the top of your file?